# Local features descriptor and Fisher Vector

Tags: matlab, opencv, vector, sift

I would like to test Fisher vector with given local features describe by (SIFT, SURF or etc). I have new in this area, and I do some research on the link [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38372-fast-gmm-and-fisher-vectors/content/html/test_yael_gmm.html), i follow the example 3 where end up error of denseSIFT is unknown. I further debug and found no solution how to fix it. Then i come across VL_SIFT at [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)but unfortunately some error `'Error using vl_impattern'`. Maybe I'm not familiar with Matlab so I decide to check with C++ opencv solutions, but I can't find and sample code for local feature encode with Fisher Vector. 
Do anyone can share some tutorial or source where i can learn and implement (prefer c++ or matlab)?

Thanks

Comment: Check[HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d) for opencv 2.4 and [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html#gsc.tab=0) for opencv 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following tutorials they are from 'Department of Engineering Science, University of Oxford'

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/overview/index.html